# What's a better approach to get multiple resources using RESTful endpoints?

Tags: rest

Hi I'm trying to design a RESTful endpoint that can benefit using Squid caching. I have two approach to designing this REST but I'm not sure which is a better practice. The first gets a list of student IDs and you need to perform a single fetch to get the individual record. The second gets all the records and has pagination. The second also has singular resource get function.

Thanks,

GET classroom/{classroomId}/students

Response:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

GET classroom/{classroomId}/students/1

Response:

```
{"studentId":1,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"}
```

**OR**

GET classroom/{classroomId}/students

Response:

```
{
items:[
{{"studentId":1,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"},
{"studentId":2,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"},
{"studentId":3,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"},
{"studentId":4,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"}}]
startIndex:0,
limit:4
}
```

GET classroom/{classroomId}/students/1

Response:

```
{"studentId":1,"firstname","abc","lastname":"def"}
```